# How to close a ngDialog from angular controller

Tags: ng-dialog

I need to open multiple ngDialog with same id, when clicking the close button it should close only the currently opened ngDialog.

For closing ngDialog I need to call one event which collects the data then closes the ngDialog.

Answer (score 8):

It depends if you're trying to close it (1) from its own controller, or (2) the controller that instantiates it:

(1) From its own controller:

```
scope.closeThisDialog(value);
```

see doc: https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog

(2) From controller that instantiates it:

```
var dialog = ngDialog.open(); 
// for closing the dialog call dialog.close()
```

As mentioned by Satish Salvador's response.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Assign the ngDialog.open() to a variable like `var dialog = ngDialog.open();` for closing the dialog call `dialog.close()`

Comment: this is correct if you are closing dialog from same function , but if you are opening dialog from one function , how can you close it inside another function ?

Comment: @MichaelFulton did you find the solution for it?

Comment: @HumanLove Yes my issue was fixed good enough for my purposes by disabling animations. I have posted an answer. You can specify the disableAnimations option when creating the dialog. Issues thread described here https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog/issues/319#issuecomment-215273260

Comment: @Arash You could have the var dialog outside the function, check the dialog state on function call with the var dialog and perform your actions

Answer (score 2):

**You could use `.getOpenDialogs()`**

There is a method on `ngDialog` object called `getOpenDialogs`. What you could with this function is to get a list of all opened dialogs and close the one you are interested in by calling `.close()` on the "selected" one.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, you can avoid this issue by specifying disableAnimation options when creating the dialog:

```
ngDialog.open({
  template: 'template.html',
  appendClassName: 'ngdialog-custom',
  disableAnimation: true
});
```

Comment: It worked in my case but I would like to know the exact reason for this. @michael-fulton Can you please explain this.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond `closeThisDialog()` you can do:

```
vm.myDialog = ngDialog.open(... omissis ...);
...
vm.myDialog.close();
```

or

```
vm.myDialog = ngDialog.open(... omissis ...);
...
ngDialog.close(vm.myDialog.id);
```